# select single row based on count of rows present oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I've got below table using a query, Now I want to fetch single record based on conditions explained below and assign it to two variable i.e. `v_dte_meeting` and `v_status_meeting` declared in my stored procedure,

```
 Dte_Meeting| Ststus_Meeting
########################
15-Oct-14   | Due    
30-Oct-14   | Due
15-Dec-14   | Init
30-Dec-14   | Init
30-Nov-15   | Approved
```

I want to assign value to these variables based on below conditions:

1. If a a single or multiple records present with Status_Meeting as 'Due' Then assign v_dte_meeting the greatest date with 'Due' status and assign v_status_meeting with value 'Due'
2. If above condition fails then, check If a single or multiple records present with Ststus_Meeting as 'Init' If it does,  Then assign v_dte_meeting the greatest date with 'Init' status and assign v_status_meeting with value 'Init'
3. If both condition fails then assign both variables NULL value

Please help me to do it the best way in Oracle

Comment: You should edit your question and provide the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. I am only showing the SELECT statement (I didn't create variables, so I am not selecting INTO, but that wasn't your difficulty, you know how to do that.) I use subquery factoring (the WITH clause), available only in versions >= 11 I believe, otherwise you can rewrite to put the subqueries where they belong.

Note the use of rank(); in Gordon's solution, he will pick up max(dte) over ALL rows, not just those with status = 'Due', so it can't be as simple as what he wrote. EDIT: I also don't see where he selects NULL, NULL if neither 'Due' nor 'Init' are present. (Sorry for the abuse, this should be a comment to his answer, I lack privileges.)

```
WITH t (Date_Meeting, Status_Meeting) AS
   (
      SELECT TO_DATE('15-OCT-14', 'DD-MON-YY'), 'Due' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('30-OCT-14', 'DD-MON-YY'), 'Due' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('15-DEC-14', 'DD-MON-YY'), 'Init' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('30-DEC-14', 'DD-MON-YY'), 'Init' FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('15-NOV-15', 'DD-MON-YY'), 'Approved' FROM dual
   ),
     s (Date_Meeting, Status_Meeting) AS
   (
      SELECT Date_Meeting, Status_Meeting FROM t 
            WHERE Status_Meeting = 'Due' OR Status_Meeting = 'Init'
      UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL FROM dual  -- To ensure you have the nulls if needed
   ),
    r (Date_Meeting, Status_Meeting, rk) AS
   (
      SELECT Date_Meeting, Status_Meeting, 
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DECODE(Status_Meeting, 'Due', 0, 'Init', 1, 2), 
                          Date_Meeting DESC)  -- make sure you understand this
      FROM s
   )
SELECT Date_Meeting, Status_Meeting FROM r WHERE rk = 1
/
```

Result:

```
DATE_MEET STATUS_M
--------- --------
30-OCT-14 Due

1 row selected.
```

Comment: yes.. I noticed the date was incorrect using max(dte) your solution worked quite well but its just that I didn't want to use more than one outer query.(I know cte 'r' can be eliminated here) I've done it another way using group by with a single outer query. Still just curious to know, does using CTE have any performance advantage over subquery?

Comment: Only if you avoid writing the same subquery in more than one place. Otherwise it's probably about the same (at compilation time, "r" is rewritten as a subquery anyway, so at execution it makes no difference). The biggest difference is in readability of your code, making it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select (case when sum(case when status_meeting = 'Due' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when status_meeting = 'Due' dte_meeting end)
             when sum(case when status_meeting = 'Init' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when status_meeting = 'Init' then dte_meeting end)
        end),  
       (case when sum(case when status_meeting = 'Due' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then'Due'
             when sum(case when status_meeting = 'Init' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Init'
        end)
into v_dte_meeting, v_status_meeting
from t;
```

However, I think a simpler version just uses `order by`:

```
select max(dte_meeting), max(status_meeting)
into v_dte_meeting, v_status_meeting
from (select t.*
      from t
      where status_meeting in ('Due', 'Init')
      order by (case when status_meeting = 'Due' then 1
                     when status_meeting = 'Init' then 2
                end)
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

The `max()` is just to ensure that exactly one row is returned.